# How do I place my buttons inside the gray frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm trying to put my 3 buttons inside the gray frame (labeled mainframe), even though I put the parent of the buttons as the frame.

```
import tkinter

class theUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("500x600")
        self.mainframe = tkinter.Frame(self.root, height=300, width=400, bg="gray").pack(side="left")
        tkinter.Button(master=self.mainframe, text="Rock").pack(side="left")
        tkinter.Button(master=self.mainframe, text="Paper").pack()
        tkinter.Button(master=self.mainframe, text="Scissors").pack(side="right")

        self.root.mainloop()


game = theUI()
```

I tried using pack and grid but they both gave me the same issue. I just started using tkinter so I'm still learning how the widgets work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `self.mainframe` is `None` because it is the result of `.pack(...)`. So the buttons will be children of root window because their parent is `None`.

You need to separate the following line:

```py
self.mainframe = tkinter.Frame(self.root, height=300, width=400, bg="gray").pack(side="left")
```

into two lines:

```py
self.mainframe = tkinter.Frame(self.root, height=300, width=400, bg="gray")
self.mainframe.pack(side="left")
```